# custom keyboard height swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a keyboard for my app :
[image]
As you can see when running on iPhone 8 the keyboard is overlapping the boxes. Now I cannot set constraints to the boxes because the keyboard only appear once the boxes already been created. How can I make sure it won't overlap the keyboard?
this is how I set the keyboard height:

```swift
keyboardView = Keyboard.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height/2.5))
```

Also, do apple even allow keyboards like this inside apps or are they not going to publish the app if it has custom keyboard?

Thank you!